# Tools for manual disambiguation/editing of match results

Tags: clustering, data-quality

We are using a clustering approach to find data that is present in multiple datasets. Eg, if a product is sold on Barnes & Noble and Amazon, we want to know that it's the same product.

The algorithm spits out 3 lists of data:

- High confidence that a pair of rows are the same
- Unsure if two rows are the same (low confidence either way)
- High confidence that two rows are *not* the same

We want a manual process to do the following:

1. Evaluate if our high confidence matches are correct (useful during development)
2. Disambiguate "unsure" results

I can't for the life of me work out (a) what this kind of process is called and (b) what tools are out there to help us do this. We've resorted to manually inspecting CSVs in Excel and labelling columns. At some point we can stop doing process 1 once our pipeline is good enough, but we will always have a need for process 2.

NB this isn't really human-in-the-loop as commonly described, because the results of the human QA don't get pumped back into training data (there is no training data - it's clustering).

Comment: > the results of the human QA don't get pumped back into training data (there is no training data - it's clustering)
So why do you evaluate at all?

Comment: @Valentas because we can still identify patterns how the clustering works, and tweaks clustering weights based on that (eg do we weight a field more or less). yes, that could be an ML process, which this data could form the basis for, but for now manual is simpler. And if we did do an ML process to tune cluster weights, then we would still need a way to capture that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that this kind of problem is best solved by rolling your own solution. Here are the options I evaluted:

- Google Sheets. Simple, dirty. Can integrate with Databricks via a library.
- Streamlit. Nicer than Sheets, can create the app in Python.
- Retool. Simpler than Streamlit but not necessarily targeted at data apps.